# Why won't my volume control work?

Tags: sound, drivers, gnome

I recently installed Gnome 3 in Ubuntu 11.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T61p. Since then, my hard volume buttons have stopped working, and my manual volume control via the top-right corner has had no impact on whether or not my computer releases sounds. As a matter of fact, I seem to have no OS-wide volume control whatsoever: it's always on. Going into the Gnome 3 "Sound Settings" makes me feel like there might be drivers missing, as it doesn't recognize any of my hardware, or acknowledge that said hardware exists.

I imagine this has something to do with drivers, but the drivers were working fine until I installed Gnome 3. So I suppose my main question is "Why isn't Gnome 3 listed as the alpha software it is?" with a hefty side of "does anybody know what happened to my sound drivers," and "is there a magic wand I can wave to get them all back?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed a PPA for Gnome 3? That's why you can't install it from the repo's. Everything from a PPA should be thought of as alpha. What directions did you use to install it?

Comment: Uh... Too many. Too many different sets of directions, because no one of them got the job done. I have no idea what a PPA is, but I've seen enough instructions that involve them that I tried that without question. At first, it failed. Then, I was told to go into the software center, add the ppa to my software sources (instead of via the command line), and then a whole Gnome 3 section showed up on the left side of my software center, and I just forced it to work from there. It was totally legit.

Comment: If it had been legit, you wouldn't have forced it to work or used so many different sets of instructions.

Comment: That last sentence was supposed to be sarcasm. Anyway, my audio is working again... But the question still stands, I guess: does gnome 3 mess with your drivers?

Comment: I suppose you did at least answer the question -- it won't work because I installed shady software.